# RequireActual for a manual mock

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

Searched everywhere, but couldn't find.

I'm mocking axios in a manual mock __mocks__/axios.js:

```js
let mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')
// mockAxios = jest.requireActual('axios')

export default mockAxios
```

But sometimes I want to use the actual axios implementation (like what the commented out line does).

In my test axios is not used directly. So I tried to undo manual mock for that test suite:

```js
test('200 response', async () => {
    jest.mock("axios", () => jest.requireActual("axios"))
    const response = await getContent('SomeID')
    expect(response.id).toEqual('SomeID');
  })
```

This doesn't seem to change anything and the test fails because axios.get doesn't return anything useful.

Is there a way to have a test, or a test file where manual mock is not used at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use [`jest.dontMock(moduleName)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdontmockmodulename) to let specific test cases use the real module implementation.

Don't forget to reset the module registry - the cache of all required modules. [`jest.resetModules()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/jest-object#jestresetmodules) will do this.

E.g.

`__mocks__/axios.js`:

```js
let mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios')

mockAxios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'fake' })

export default mockAxios
```

`main.ts`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function main() {
  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```
describe('76428962', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  })
  test('should mock axios', async () => {
    const { main } = await import('./main');
    const actual = await main();
    console.log(actual?.data);
  });
  test('should not mock axios', async () => {
    jest.dontMock('axios');
    const { main } = await import('./main');
    const actual = await main();
    console.log(actual?.data);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.log
    fake

      at stackoverflow/76428962/main.test.ts:8:13

 PASS  stackoverflow/76428962/main.test.ts (15.823 s)
  76428962
    ✓ should mock axios (96 ms)
    ✓ should not mock axios (208 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.28 s, estimated 19 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
  console.log
    { userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }

      at stackoverflow/76428962/main.test.ts:14:13
```

Comment: That worked. But then I was also able to get `jest.mock("axios", () => jest.requireActual("axios"))` to work as well. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!